# How to remove an instance of an object so a new, updated one can take over?

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism, instance

In my game, I declare a PlayerClass (warrior/rogue/etc) like so:

```
    public PlayerClass playerClass;
```

On the first frame of the game (for now) I instantiate my player's PlayerClass like so:

```
    playerClass = new WarriorClass(player, 100);
```

This works great. The WarriorClass lets my player use some abilities. However, now I'd like to make my player a rogue:

```
    playerClass = new RogueClass(player, 100);
```

But for whatever reason, I now have two instances, not one. I push my ability button and it triggers both the Warrior and Rogue ability.

How do I wipe or remove the WarriorClass reference before assigning the new Rogue one?

What also happens if that I exit to the main menu and log into the game again, my player has two instances of the WarriorClass. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Ultimately, the source of my problem is that I don't understand why playerClass isn't getting overwritten each time like another variable would.

Comment: In WarriorClass and RgoueClass, do you keep a reference of player object?

Comment: This is too broad, we shouldn't be expected to know what your menu or logout functions do. We also shouldn't be expected to know how your player object is handled. Add some more information!

Comment: Oh ok, this is a mod for Terraria using tModLoader. I don't know the answers to that @BlakeConnally. I thought answer to "why isn't playerClass being overwritten" would be a simple one. All I'm doing is the above when the game starts.

Comment: @MuhammedYusuf I do pass along a reference to my player to my PlayerClass and then the Ability class and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all references of your `player` object in your `PlayerClass`.

Create a method called `Destroy()` in your PlayerClasses(WarriorClass, RogueClass) and call this method whenever you will create a new object.

```
public void Destroy(){
    this.player = null;
    //remove all other references, stop tasks-threads if exists. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not giving enough info. I didn't understand my problem enough to know what to give. I had implemented an idea that I didn't realize was causing the bug. I was holding onto a list of Abilities and not clearing them on game start. Every game start would append more to it:

In player:

```
    public List<Ability> ActiveAbilities = new List<Ability>();
```

Appending to that in each PlayerClass instantiation:

```
        ability1 = new LeapAbility();
        player.GetModPlayer<MyPlayer>().ActiveAbilities.Add(ability1);
```

At that point my keybinds would be triggering everything in the list. The fix in player:

```
        ActiveAbilities.Clear();
        playerClass = new TestClass(player, 100);
```